# Want a select query where database data represented as column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have a database table named as sales.

```
| ID  |  Group  |   Month  | Amt |
____________________________________
 1    | Y       | Dec-2015 | 300
___________________________________
 2    | Z       | Dec-2015 | 250
___________________________________
 1    | Y       | Nov-2015 | 320
____________________________________
 2    | Z       | Nov-2015 | 430
```

I want output as following table

```
| ID  |  group  | Dec-2015| Nov-2015
___________________________________
 1    | Y       |    300  |  320
___________________________________
 2    | Z       |   250   |  430
____________________________________
```

I hope you get my requirement now. I am not very good at Sql. i hope you can help , Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the expected result if a Oct-2014 value suddenly shows up in your table?

Comment: Search for **Dynamic Pivot**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, GROUP, MONTH, AMT
) p
PIVOT
(
    SUM(AMT) FOR MONTH IN ([Dec-2015], [Nov-2015])
) AS pvt
```

Which will get the rows as columns, then:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Group, SUM([Dec-2015]), SUM([Nov-2015])
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, GROUP, MONTH, AMT
) p
PIVOT
(
    SUM(AMT) FOR MONTH IN ([Dec-2015], [Nov-2015])
) AS pvt
GROUP BY
    ID,
    GROUP
```

To sum up the amounts and group by `ID` and `Group`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working. But i get multiple id and row. Means each row is for a month other rows are null. Like showing AMT for Dec-2015 and Nov-2015 is null , in next row showing AMT for Nove-2015 and Dec-2015 is null.

Comment: I have changed it to include the aggregations. It may include an `IFNULL` around the `SUM` statements, but should work.